# Pyspark decimal type precision issue

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I was trying to read data from oracle DB and save the data into s3 bucket. My oracle datatype is "NUMBER" and I want to bring the data as it is. While Spark default decimal-type precision is messing up my data.

I googled and tried to set the `spark.sql.decimalOperations.allowPrecissionLoss` to false but it doesn't seem it helped me at all. This is what I want.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.decimalOperations.allowPrecisionLoss", False)

data = [{"ID": 2, "how_it_is_in_oracledb": 0.721747448731, 'how_spark_currently_reading_it': 0.7217474487, 'how_i_want_spark_to_read_it': 0.721747448731},
        {"ID": 3, "how_it_is_in_oracledb": 0.721809026655, 'how_spark_currently_reading_it': 0.7218090267, 'how_i_want_spark_to_read_it': 0.721809026655},
        {"ID": 4, "how_it_is_in_oracledb": 1.11923723305, 'how_spark_currently_reading_it': 1.1192372331, 'how_i_want_spark_to_read_it': 1.11923723305},
        {"ID": 5, "how_it_is_in_oracledb": 1.4181928904, 'how_spark_currently_reading_it': 1.4181928904, 'how_i_want_spark_to_read_it': 1.4181928904},
        {"ID": 6, "how_it_is_in_oracledb": 1.722053514419, 'how_spark_currently_reading_it': 1.7220535144, 'how_i_want_spark_to_read_it': 1.722053514419}
        ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show(truncate=False)

+---+---------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
|ID |how_i_want_spark_to_read_it|how_it_is_in_oracledb|how_spark_currently_reading_it|
+---+---------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
|2  |0.721747448731             |0.721747448731       |0.7217474487                  |
|3  |0.721809026655             |0.721809026655       |0.7218090267                  |
|4  |1.11923723305              |1.11923723305        |1.1192372331                  |
|5  |1.4181928904               |1.4181928904         |1.4181928904                  |
|6  |1.722053514419             |1.722053514419       |1.7220535144                  |
+---+---------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Did you try to enforce a predefined schema ? . Additionally try casting to decimal with appropriate precision and scale within your sql statement itself

Comment: Another crude way of doing would be to read everything as string and cast accordingly